# How to handle complex response examples using Azure OpenApi?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, openapi

Give this scenario...

```
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, 
contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(string), 
Summary = "The Response", Description = "This returns the response")]
```

this is the classic example based on documentation.

Now, check this model:

```
internal class Country
   {
    public string Iso3166 { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
   }
```

If I want to return an array of Countries, I should supply something like this...

```
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, 
contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(Country[]), 
Summary = "The Response", Description = "This returns the response")]
```

Ok, so far, so good....

But the realistic scenario always will be a response like this object...

```
internal class Response
   {
    public bool Successfully { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMsg { get; set; }
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public dynamic Data { get; set; }
   }
```

Where the list of country will be a child of Data property....
So, in my code, this behaves like:

```
var results = new List<Country>();
Response res = new Response()
        {
            Successfully = true,
            Count = results.Count,
            Data = results
        };
return new OkObjectResult(res);
```

I need to inform to the OpenApi that the response should be an object of type response and inside the Data property, always will be an array of country. How to archive it ?

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
Response res = new Response()
        {
            Successfully = true,
            Count = results.Count,
            Data = results
        };
return new OkObjectResult(res);
```

for that:

```
var response = req.CreateResponse();
response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(results);
return response;
```

Then **results** can be for any object or list.

If you need add some header, you can to do:

```
response.Headers.Add("Request-Warning", parameters.paging.Message);
```

And remember return:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseData> ...functionName
```